# Displaying image from firebase storage to android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

I have tried everything i could, but still I can't figure out why this code is not displaying image that is in the firebase storage. I got the values from the database correctly.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<prod_list,productdetails>
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
            <prod_list,productdetails>(prod_list.class,R.layout.prodlist,productdetails.class,mdatabase){

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(productdetails viewHolder, prod_list model, int position) {
            final String id=getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setprod_name(model.getProduct_name());
            viewHolder.setprod_price(model.getProduct_price());
            viewHolder.setprod_quan(model.getAvailable_stock());
            viewHolder.setimage(getActivity(),model.getProduct_image());

            viewHolder.prodview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cardviewintent=new Intent(getActivity(),Editproduct.class);
                    cardviewintent.putExtra("prod_id",id);
                    startActivity(cardviewintent);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    prodlist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

And the setimage function.

```
public void setimage(Context ctx,String image)
    {
        ImageView prod_image=(ImageView)prodview.findViewById(R.id.prod_image);
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(prod_image);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `image`?

Comment: image url from storage-com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@b555712

Comment: Yeah, that's not a URL.  That's the string form of a Cloud Storage upload task.  You'll need to get the HTTP URL from that and store it in the database.

Comment: I am sorry, com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@b555712  the string value that is stored in the firebase database. I got it by using log. Its the same value that is in  database.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Picasso needs an actual URL, not that string.

Comment: how do i get it?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  You're going to have to figure out what writes that location and fix it.

Comment: post url of image as well and storage rules